# Can I build a Visualforce Page that shows detail records and activities for 2 separate objects?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-apps

I am trying to display full record details and activity history for 2 object on a single page. The best idea I could come up with is to use a Visualforce page that can split up 2 objects on a single page. Is this possible at all?

I'd like to display my custom object called Quality_Assurance__c and standard Case object on a single page. The reason I need this is because the Cases will be QA evaluated and the user needs to reference all record details and acitivity history for the related Case. The related Case. The Quality Assurance object has a Master-Detail(Case) relationship-- not sure if this matters for this use-case.

How would I easily build Visualforce code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this in a variety of ways. For example, you can:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
  <apex:detail subject="{!caseRecord.Id}" />
  <apex:detail subject="{!qaRecord.Id}" />
</apex:page>
```

This is obviously a super-simple example, but it's your code, you can write it however you like. You'll almost certainly need an Apex controller to coordinate loading and saving the data, but the answer is most definitely "yes."